# Ubuntu Server 14.04 install hangs at Downloading Release files... 0%

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation

Title says it.  Installing Ubuntu Server 14.04 from USB.  Process goes smoothly until I hit the "Checking the Ubuntu archive mirror" screen, where it hangs at 0% forever.  Is this something my network admin needs to handle or something on my end that I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try making a fresh bootable USB stick and install.
Also check to make sure you have internet access during the installation by pressing the **askubuntu.com** link which appears on one of the features tabs. It will open up a firefox window from where you can browse the net even before ubuntu installs.

Comment: It won't let me upvote your answer because I have no rep.  Lack of internet was the problem, had to go to my sysadmin.  Are you sure you can run Firefox from an Ubuntu Server install process?  There's no mouse/GUI other than ASCII GUI.  No Gnome/etc in this distro.

Comment: Yes you can run it during the install process. I guess Firefox comes as a portable-ready to run version. I've run it several times to search for errors popping up during installation. If you don't have a mouse, just keep pressing Tab until that link is highlighted and then press enter. You can just mark the answer as the accepted answer.